# Asp.Net cultures differ for GET and POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, culture

I set the culture of my Asp.Net Core application to German like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var supportedCultures = new[] { new CultureInfo("de-DE") };

    app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
    {
        DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("de-DE"),
        SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
        SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
    });

    ...
}
```

When I am sending a value with Postman this works perfectly and everything is parsed correctly. For example if I send a value like 0,76 it is perfectly parsed to 0.76.
However, when I make a GET request to my API endpoint, it returns the value 0.76. Of course this isn't the German culture and shows some inconsistency in my API. A developer sending and receiving data to and from my API should always have the same format, which should be the German culture.

Is this a default behavior or should it both be the same format?

**EDIT:**

Below is a screenshot which shows that for a GET request, the decimal separator is still a dot and not a comma. However, when I send data with a post request, the data is formatted correctly using a comma as a decimal seperator instead of the dot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

here : https://forums.asp.net/t/2119989.aspx?JSON+formatter+and+Localization+settings

its not valid json...

```
"netValue": 120,00,
"grossValueAdded": 147,60,
```

valid json

```
"netValue": 120.00,
"grossValueAdded": 147.60,
```

you could how ever convert all your decimals to strings, and use string manipulation (not recommending) just staying

```
"netValue": "120,00",
"grossValueAdded": "147,60",
```

Comment: That totally makes sense what you say. So it is default behavior that the format of the properties differ for the different requests? The POST request contains a file therefore I need to send it of type form-data. However, all the data of a form-data request has to be of type String. I think this is the reason why Asp.Net tries to apply the culture to the properties. If I would send data as a JSON with decimal properties, would Asp.Net still apply the culture? My guess is that it wouldn't. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: I tested it and indeed, if I send the request of type JSON in the body and the property is of type decimal, Asp.Net will not attempt to apply a culture. However, if I make the property of type String, it will automatically apply the culture and thus it has to be comma separated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why it is behaving like this. Firstly, this is how my model looks like:

```
public class someDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AuftragId { get; set; }
    public string Typ { get; set; }
    public decimal KundeBrutto { get; set; }
    public decimal KundeNetto { get; set; }
    public decimal KundeMwSt { get; set; }
    public decimal FahrerBrutto { get; set; }
    public decimal FahrerNetto { get; set; }
    public decimal FahrerMwSt { get; set; }
    public decimal MwStSatz { get; set; } = (decimal)0.19;
    public string MwStLand { get; set; } = "DE";
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileUrl { get; set; }
}
```

It is obvious that some of those properties are of type `decimal`. If I return data from a GET, Asp.Net will send back a JSON with the data. As Seabizkit mentioned, a property of type decimal is alwas seperated by a dot since it is a built in type. The culture will therefore be irrelevant.

I was wondering however, why I have to send the data with the German culture though. As per my application requirements, I need to send a file along with that data so we chose to make the request of type `form-data`. The disadvantage with form-data is that everything that you send will be of type string and won't have a datatype with it. When Asp.Net sees a string, it is attempting to map that value from string to decimal. While doing this, it assumes that the string that was sent, is in the format of the culture that is applied to the server. E.g. in my case I set the culture to German on the server and therefore a value like "47,11" will map correctly to 47.11.

However, if you decide to send your data of type JSON inside your body, you can of course make those properties of type decimal and therefore you can send them seperated by a dot.
Thus you will overcome the issue sending/receiving data in different cultures:

[image]

I hope this makes sense!